# check value on 3 different cells and return true

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

```
=IFS(N15>=D15, M15="✓", O15>=2.5,"GREAT SUCCESS", TRUE,"EPIC FAIL")
```

I want to check multiple cells with if statement and only if all 3 are TRUE return 'success' but if even one of them FALSE I want to return 'fail'

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`IFS` function params are cond1, result1, cond2, result2, ... Not stacking conditions and then the results.

From your explaination, you can just use normal IF, with AND like this:

```
=IF(AND(N15>=D15,M15="✓",O15>=2.5),"GREAT SUCCESS","EPIC FAIL")
```

If all 3 are correct, print "GREAT SUCCESS", else print "FAIL".

To apply to all row, instead of copy pasting or dragging the mouse to the entire table, you can use `ARRAYFORMULA` in the first row (don't do this if you're planning to export to xls/xlsx for Excel usage).

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(AND($N$1:$N>=$D$1:$D,$M$1:$M="✓",$O$1:$O>=2.5),"GREAT SUCCESS","EPIC FAIL"))
```

Change the first row (N1, D1, M1) to your desired number, and maybe also adding the end row. (The formula above will apply to the end of sheet.)

Edit: There's another way that support both Excel and Google Sheets that support calculating the whole range with 1 formula.
You can use `MAP` and `LAMBDA`:

```
=MAP($D$1:$D,$M$1:$M,$N$1:$N,$O$1:$O,LAMBDA(d,m,n,o,IF(OR(d="",m="",n="",o=""),"",IF(AND(n>=d,m="✓",o>=2.5),"GREAT SUCCESS","EPIC FAIL"))))
```

You input 4 ranges, then naming them as `d`, `m`, `n`, `o` or anything you like within the `LAMBDA` function. After that, you do calculation with them as variables.